# Is it possible to get the specific content on the search page?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, posts, search

I am working on the WordPress search. I am using the below code to get the data on the search page.

```
$s=get_search_query();
$args = array(
                's' =>$s
            );
        
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
 if( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <ul>
 <? while( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        $query->the_post(); 
       // print_r($query);
        
?>
<li><h2><a href='<?php echo the_permalink();?>'><?php echo the_title();?></a></h2></li>
<?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php

        };

?>
```

The above code is working. I am getting the title on the page.

Now, My concern is, Is it possible to get the specific content on the page?

I mean If I use `post_content` then I am getting all the content of the page. Is it possible to display only section heading on the search page?

**using class? or using id?**

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by "display only section heading"? Is this "section heading" a custom field of a page? Did you try fetching the field with get_post_meta?

Comment: I have 5 sections on my page and on search page instated of all the content, I have to show only the section heading.. if i use the post_content then it will display all the content

Comment: You should take a look at the PHP function preg_match. If I understand you correctly you'll need to strip the post_content value to only keep the section you want.

Comment: Yes, I want only section heading... letter will change according to requirements

Comment: I am using the wpbakery plugin